# Renaming primary key column via Liquibase, autoincrement is dropped(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, rename, liquibase

given the following changelog, the table "table_person" will not have an autoIncrement on its primary key column " after execution on a MySQL database.

Thus inserts on that table will fail with a message similar to: **"SQL error (1062): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

<changeSet id="201505111301" author="sr">   
    <createTable tableName="table_person">
        <column name="table_person_id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <insert tableName="table_person">
        <column name="name" value="TestValue1" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="table_person">
        <column name="name" value="TestValue2" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </insert>

    <renameColumn oldColumnName="table_person_id" newColumnName="id" tableName="table_person" columnDataType="int"/>    
</changeSet>
```

I've tried to fix that using:

```
<addAutoIncrement tableName="table_person" columnName="id" columnDataType="int"></addAutoIncrement>
```

This will recreate the lost autoIncrement but will obviously start at index 0 again. This again leads to problems if data already exists.

My question:

*How can I rename a primary key column in Liquibase without loosing the autoIncrement on the primary key for a mySQL database?*

(Note, on postgreSQL the autoIncrement is not lost during rename of the primary key column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a limitation of mysql. The SQL ran by liquibase is `alter table table_person change table_persion_id id int` which redefines the column as simply "int".

To keep it as auto-increment you will need to use the `<modifySql>` tag to `<append>` the auto-increment/primary key/not null/etc. information to the generated SQL as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about <modifySql>
However, I guess this is just another way of accomplishing what I've done using a plain <addAutoIncrement> statement.

Do you have a suggestion about how to fix the problem with the autoIncrement starting with index 0?
How can I set the new AutoIncrement to the max-value of the old one so that the next insert won't raise a duplicate key exception?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use the `sql` tag to manually rename the column and keep the auto increment:

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE `pkey` CHANGE `keyfield` `keyfield2` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT</sql>
```

Related: [How do I rename a primary key column in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703126/how-do-i-rename-a-primary-key-column-in-mysql)